Complexity to find "short" (e.g. polynomial in diameter) decomposition of the permutation into the product of generators?
Question 1: Consider the symmetric group $S_n$ and some set of permutations $p_i$. Given permutation $g$ - what is known about the algorithmic complexity to decompose $g$ into product of $p_i$  requiring that decomposition to be somehow "short" (and assuming it exists) ? ("Short" - for example linear or polynomial in diameter of the subgroup generated by $p_i$). Any references/ideas/expectations are welcome.
Question 2:  Assume additional constraint - the subgroup generated by $p_i$ is nilpotent finite group. Can one expect that finding "short" decomposition would have polynomial complexity in that case ?
Context:

Schreier-Sims seems NOT to be  effective:
Carlo Beenakker: MO474712 "The Schreier-Sims algorithm is highly inefficient, as explained here."  Igor Pak comment here:  "the word lengths can increase exponentially, so if you want to write an explicit word - the Schreier–Sims is useless".

Finding OPTIMAL (i.e. the shortest length) is known to be hard problem, even for some particular choices of generators: "Solving the Rubik's Cube Optimally is NP-complete" (see also: TCS783), "Bill Gates pancake sorting problem": "Pancake Flipping Is Hard". For generic generators and given integer "K" determining can element be decomposed as product of "K" generators is NP-hard:  "The minimum-length generator sequence problem is NP-hard"( S. Even, O. Goldreich 1981) and also "complete for PSPACE with respect to log-space reducibility" (M. Jerrum 1985). See also MO139469.


So finding constantly short decompositions - is hard, without shortness constraint it is not, but what is in between seems to be not so clear.

Relevant survey:
https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3653295 "Rearrangement Distance Problems: An updated survey" - on specific generators of permutation groups which relevant to bioinformatics.

Related:
Distribution of Segment Lengths in Genome Rearrangements | The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics
https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v15i1r105

Here's another relevant reference: Rubik's for cryptographers.

An introduction to computational group theory
A Seress
Notices of the AMS, 1997•ams.org
https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/199706/seress.pdf?adat=June/July%201997&trk=199706seress&cat=feature&galt=none

"Unfortunately the actual representation derived from that algorithm are usually exponentially long"
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3501931_Planning_and_learning_in_permutation_groups
Planning and learning in permutation groups
Amos Fiat
S. Moses
A. Shamir
Ilan Shimshoni

[HTML] Parameterized algorithms in bioinformatics: an overview
https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4893/12/12/256
